# pandas loop on elements

Tags: python, performance, pandas, loops, dataframe

I would like to compute delta time in a dataframe (with some condition) so I write a loop:

```
for i in range(1,len(df.index)):
    if df.type[i] == df.type[i-1]:
        df.delta[i]=df.time[i]-df.time[i-1]
    else:
        df.delta[i]= ''
```

but it seems not very optimised because it's very long and I get a `SettingWithCopyWarning` (which I don't understand). What is the best way to do such a computation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a vectorised approach. For example, you can use `numpy.where` with `pd.Series.shift` and `pd.Series.diff`:

```
df['C_id'] = np.where(df['type'] == df['type'].shift(), df['time'].diff(), np.nan)
```

Note I strongly recommend you do **not** use an empty string `''` as your alternative value, as this will force your series to have `object` dtype instead of `float`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use .shift() for that. It makes a new column with values shifted by 1.
So if we have no conditions, you'll need just `df["time"] - df["time"].shift()`, but as you want to add condition, `where` would help. So here is a one line solution

```
(df["time"] - df["time"].shift()).where(df["type"] == df["type"].shift(), "")
```

Or as suggested in other answer, you can use diff

```
df["time"].diff().where(df["type"] == df["type"].shift(), "")
```

Answer (score 0):

my approach would be to use pandas.apply()

```
type_prev = ''
time_prev = 0

def lambda_func(row):
    global type_prev
    global time_prev
    if row['type'] == time_prev:
        time_diff = row['time'] - time_prev
    else:
        time_diff = ''
    time_prev = row['time']
    type_prev = row['type']
    return time_diff

df['delta'] = df.apply(lambda_func)
```

Comment: it seems that it doesn't work, try this : 
   
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
    df.A[0:2] = 1
    df.A[2:5] = 4
    df.A[5:9] = 3
    type_prev = ''
    time_prev = 0
    
    def lambda_func(row):
        global type_prev
        global time_prev
        if row['A'] == time_prev:
            time_diff = row['B'] - time_prev
        else:
            time_diff = ''
        time_prev = row['B']
        type_prev = row['A']
        return time_diff
    
    df['C'] = df.apply(lambda_func)